# Laws implementation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In the lecture that the teacher gave me, the following equation

~[(~p∨q)∧ ~(r∨~q)]

~[~(p∧q)∧(~p∧q)] (using DeMorgans Law)

I think that the final output is false
I want to know that is it really false or I didn't understand well.
if its wrong then would you please share the right answer so I can understand

Comment: But an $r$ changed into a $p$ ????? This is a typo for sure.

Comment: But you are right: there is an error. Assuming that the first formula is $¬[(¬p∨q)∧¬(p∨¬q)]$ we have: $¬[(¬p∨q)∧(¬p∧q)]$ and then $¬[¬(p∧¬q)∧(¬p∧q)]$